# Roboblender use annotation databases with multiple modules

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-injection, roboguice, roboblender

I'm following the steps from the [RoboBlender Wiki](https://github.com/roboguice/roboguice/wiki/RoboBlender-wiki) to use annotations database but I keep getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to use annotation database(s)` because it cannot find `AnnotationDatabaseImpl`

I am using Android Studio and Gradle. The project consists of multiple modules.

- app
- moduleA
- moduleB
- moduleC

Here is what I added to my build scripts:

app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
  provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.0.1'
  provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.0.1'
}
project.tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { task ->
    options.compilerArgs << "-AguiceAnnotationDatabasePackageName=com.sample.myapp"
}
```

module[x]/build.gradle:

```
project.tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { task ->
    options.compilerArgs << "-AguiceAnnotationDatabasePackageName=com.sample.module[x]"
}
```

On the Application Object:

```
 RoboGuice.setUseAnnotationDatabases(true);
 RoboGuice.getOrCreateBaseApplicationInjector(this, RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE,
 RoboGuice.newDefaultRoboModule(this), new MyModule());
        RoboGuice.injectMembers(this, this);
```

Am I missing something? I found some similar questions but they weren't very useful.

Update:
I forgot to add it on the first time but yes I am including the manifest meta.

```
<meta-data android:name="roboguice.modules" android:value="your.package.MyModule"/>  
<meta-data android:name="roboguice.annotations.packages" android:value="com.sample.myapp,com.sample.modulex,com.sample.moduley"/>
```

Update 2:
I finally found the problem. Proguard was deleting the class. Fixed by adding:

```
-keep public class * extends com.google.inject.AnnotationDatabase
```

Comment: If you found the problem then please answer your question and accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some hours I found the problem. It was proguard. Adding the following line fixed the issue.

```
-keep public class * extends com.google.inject.AnnotationDatabase
```

You can check that the classes are being generated by running in the project folder:

```
find . | grep -i AnnotationDatabaseImpl
```

Comment: Can you post your whole build.gradle?... I'm not being able to run RoboBlender under AndroidStudio.

Answer (score 2):

Did you list your module and your annotation databases in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

```
    <meta-data android:name="roboguice.modules" android:value="your.package.MyModule"/>  
    <meta-data android:name="roboguice.annotations.packages" android:value="com.sample.myapp,com.sample.modulex,com.sample.moduley"/>
```

Comment: Yes Im listing modules and annotation databases. I forgot to add it to the question. Thanks